# Zurb Foundation 5 Top Bar Drop Down not

Tags: jquery, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I'm integrating Zurb Foundation 5 into a WordPress theme and have came into a a bit of a roadblock. All JS elements appear to be working, but the drop down menu does not work.

The mobile nav works fine, so the issue is only when the nav is full size.

I'm assuming this is a JS/jQuery issue, so I decided to post a live link as I don't believe the issue is in the code.

http://jointswp.com/demo/features/

As you can see, other JS elements are working fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Your error lies within your syntax:

```
<ul/ class="dropdown" />
```

line 82 column 5 - Error: A slash was not immediately followed by >.
line 82 column 24 - Error: Self-closing syntax (/>) used on a non-void HTML element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag.

Comment: Thank you for catching that! I fixed that issue, but the menu still isn't dropping down.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having the same problem so I checked the documentation for the Foundation 5 topbar and you need to add data-topbar to the opening  tag. Please see below:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
```

Doing this fixed the dropdowns for me.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never!

I had this same issue, after using my mighty google-fu I found a few various ways in which people have fixed it. However none of which helped with my issue! DRAT!!

Then after face-palming myself to oblivion I thought I would go the simple route!

Appearance -> Customize. Then assign my navigation in the theme options. VOLA! It worked!

I even tried rewriting the theme functions before I realised my mistake ...

Oh well, it now works and it serves as a reminded to check the theme options first!